# Want to find absolute value using fabs and my own absolute value function

Tags: c

Trying to learn functions by playing around with the library and creating my own code. I created my own absolute value func to compare and contrast.

```
expected input: -10
expected output: The library absolute value of -10 is 10
                 My absolute value of -10 is 10
```

I'm getting errors about char and int a not being there.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int absolute(int a);

int main () {

   int a;

   printf("%d", "Enter a number and I will tell you the absolute value: ");
   scanf("%d", &a);

   printf("The library absolute value of %d is %lf\n", a, fabs(a));
   printf("My absolute value of %d is %lf\n", a, absolute(a));

   return(0);
}

int absolute(int a){
   return a*((2*a+1)%2); 
}
```

Errors:

```
funcab.c:10:4: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat=]
    printf("%d", "Enter a number and I will tell you the absolute value: ", a);
funcab.c:14:4: warning: format ‘%lf’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 3 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
    printf("My absolute value of %d is %lf\n", a, absolute(a));
```

Comment: When posting questions about errors, please copy-paste (as text) the full and complete error output into the question body. And mark out (with comments) where in the code the errors are.

Comment: `absolute` returns an `int`, not a `double`, so `%lf` in the third `printf` should be `%d`.

Comment: Why do you have a `"%d", ` and `, a` in that first `printf`?

Comment: Note `a*((2*a+1)%2)` fails for large `int` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not correct:

```
printf("%d", "Enter a number and I will tell you the absolute value: ", a);
```

The first argument to `printf` is a format string, and the following arguments are values that fulfill that format string.  Your format string is  `"%d"` which means you intend to print an `int`, but the next argument is a string.

Since you just want to print a string, make that the format:

```
printf("Enter a number and I will tell you the absolute value: ");
```

This is also a problem:

```
printf("My absolute value of %d is %lf\n", a, absolute(a));
```

Because the `%lf` format specifier expects a `double` but `absolute` returns an `int`.  Because of the variardic nature of `printf`, the `int` is not implicitly converted to a `double`, so you have a format string argument mismatch.  You should use `%d` instead:

```
printf("My absolute value of %d is %d\n", a, absolute(a));
```

Comment: @HenryGibbs Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.